# Getting 401 error, reason:Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket

Tags: json, google-app-engine, http-headers, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a  `.jpeg` file to google cloud storage but my request fails with the following 401 error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket XXXtest.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket XXXtest."
 }
}
```

My POST request looks like this.

```
<form id="upload_image_form" class="" action="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/XXXtest/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="image" name="image" type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="">

    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="my_name">
    <input type="hidden" name="Accept" value="application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript">
    <input type="hidden" name="host" value="www.googleapis.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="Transfer-Encoding" value="chunked">
    <input type="hidden" name="Authorization" value="<?php echo 'Bearer'.' '.$_SESSION['access_token']['access_token']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Expect" value="100-continue">
    <input type="hidden" name="Accept-Encoding" value="gzip, deflate">
    <input type="hidden" name="Connection" value="Keep-Alive">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-writer">
    <input id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" type="submit" style="position: absolute;">

</form>
```

Can you please tell me what am I missing according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert)?

Comment: did you check/set the ACLs? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists

Comment: Whoa, you really don't want to do this! You're passing an access token to your end user in the form. Not only will that not work, it also gives anyone who views that page a token that they can use to do anything they want with that user's credentials. It is like including your password in an HTML comment.

Comment: Hi @DanCornilescu yeah I set that with value "bucket-owner-writer" but its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow users to upload objects to GCS via a form POST, you're going to need to create a "policy document" describing what sort of objects the user can upload, then sign it, then pass that signed doc as a parameter in the form. You can read more about uploading to GCS via a POST here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object

And note especially the section on signed policy documents here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

Here's an example policy document:

```
{"expiration": "2010-06-16T11:11:11Z",
 "conditions": [
  ["starts-with", "$key", "" ],
  {"acl": "bucket-owner-read" },
  {"bucket": "travel-maps"},
  {"success_action_redirect": "http://www.example.com/success_notification.html" },
  ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg" ],
  ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000]
  ]
}
```

You'd then base64 that document, sign the result with the private key for the service account you want the user to act as for purposes of the upload, and then provide them in hidden fields, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTAtMDYtMTZUMTE6MTE6MTFaIiwNCiAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICJrZXkiLCAiIiBdLA0KICB7ImFjbCI6ICJidWNrZXQtb3duZXItcmVhZCIgfSwNCiAgeyJidWNrZXQiOiAidHJhdmVsLW1hcHMifSwNCiAgeyJzdWNjZXNzX2FjdGlvbl9yZWRpcmVjdCI6ICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3Nfbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uLmh0bWwiIH0sDQogIFsiZXEiLCAiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlL2pwZWciIF0sDQogIFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLCAwLCAxMDAwMDAwXQ0KICBdDQp9">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="BSAMPLEaASAMPLE6SAMPLE+SAMPPLEqSAMPLEPSAMPLE+SAMPLEgSAMPLEzCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw=">
```

Comment: Hi Brandon. Thanks for this useful information. I am new to google cloud. I don't know how to create this document (may be a silly question). May I know whether we have to create a file with above configuration and include encoded file path or do something else in the code?

Comment: The policy document is a JSON string that has been encoded using base64 and is passed to GCS as part of the POST request as a hidden input. You can either declare it as a constant in your code, or else you could generate one using a JSON and a base64 library on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I got succeed to accomplish this using following code. I did that using cloud `api` methods given here [Resumable uploading to Google Cloud Storage using PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872851/resumable-uploading-to-google-cloud-storage-using-php-api)