# how to upload multiple files like a bulk insert on google cloud storage

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following situation. I'm using laravel and google cloud storage so basically, I have my own custom filesystem attached to google cloud storage. My code looks like this -

```
try{
    $disk = Storage::disk('gcs');

                $disk->put('/service_provider/transports/tech_passports', $file1);
                $disk->put('/service_provider/transports/tech_passports', $file2);

                $disk->put('/service_provider/transports/pictures', $file3);
                $disk->put('/service_provider/transports/pictures', $file4);
                $disk->put('/service_provider/transports/pictures', $file5);
                $disk->put('/service_provider/transports/pictures', $file6);
    } catch(\Exception $e){

}
```

Now i'm worried. what if the first three files get uploaded and the fourth one has an error. so it will go to catch block and finally, only 3 files will be uploaded which is not what I need.

What I need is all get uploaded or no file gets uploaded just like atomicity. how do I achieve that?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage supports "atomicity" only for a single object upload to a storage bucket. If you want atomicity for a group of files, you will need to upload one at a time or in parallel. If any part of the group upload fails you will need to delete the other sucessful objects.

Comment: what if it fails when trying to delete successful objects?

Comment: There are a number of issues, such as failing to delete, that your code or library will need to handle. In the case of a delete failing, for example your connect drops, you will need to keep track of state to recover at a later time. There is no "Google Cloud Storage Solution" to guarantee that a group of files will either upload as a "transaction" or completely fail. You will have to implement this yourself.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that all your files get uploaded, try using [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload) on each of your individual files, with the following steps:

Initiate upload > Process response > Upload The file > Check Upload Status > Process response > Resume the upload

Retry last three steps to resume upload as many times as necessary or implement another solution (for example: delete all files already uploaded), if it is what you need in your application.

You can also check [Google Cloud Storage API PHP resumable behavior in the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872851/resumable-uploading-to-google-cloud-storage-using-php-api) from another question on StackOverflow.

Please note that also [Cloud SDK utility Gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) has resumable upload implemented in it. It can be used to [Synchronize content of two buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)/directories.

---